# How to simplify SQL query to get the result

Tags: sql

I have table "questions" (with date field and questions_id field)
and table "answers" consisting of question_id and user_id.

Each user could leave many answers to one question.

I need to get such table(grouped by date):
date|all_answers_count|user_1_answers_count

Is it possible to write simpler query to get table?

```
SELECT date, all_answers_count, user_1_answers_count
FROM
( 
SELECT date, COUNT(user_id) as all_answers_count|
FROM questions
JOIN answers
ON questions.question_id == answers.question_id
) as t1
JOIN
(
SELECT date, COUNT(user_id) as user_1_answers_count
FROM questions
JOIN answers
ON questions.question_id == answers.question_id
WHERE user_id == 1
) as t2
ON t1.date == t2.date
```

Comment: Yes it's possible. TAG your RDBMS, add sample data and desired results. Does that even run? `==` is not ANSI SQL.

Comment: Well I don’t use particular RDBMS. I am solving it on a paper. It seems to me that this is a typical task and little depends on RDBMS, am I wrong?

Comment: `select q.date, count(*) as all_answers, sum(case when a.user_id = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as user1_answers from questions q inner join answers a on q.question_id = a.question_id group by q.date` might help. If the output requires data only from answers table, you may not need to join questions table with answers.